# How to get a submap from a node Object?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I am trying to get a submap of person node in Neo4j using apoc procedures.

I tried using apoc.map.submap() function which I found in neo4j apoc documentation. My cypher query looks like this:

```
MATCH (p:person)
    RETURN  apoc.map.submap(p{.*}, ["name", "id"],null, true)
```

Expected results:

```
{
    "name" : "Tom",
    "id" : 23
}
```

Output:

Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Unknown function 'apoc.map.submap'

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Is there a reason why `RETURN p {.name, .id}` won't work for you? The apoc function will throw an exception if one of the keys doesn't exist, but if you don't need that the Cypher provided should do the trick. Oh, and I guess the apoc version works better for dynamic keys.

Comment: It threw an exception and I changed true to false in apoc.map.submap(p{.*}, ["name", "id"],null, false). Then it worked. And you are right! My only reason is dynamic attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run your query on my Neo4j, I don't get the unknown procedure error.
You most likely didn't install the APOC plugin on your Neo4j server. Here is how to do it: [Apoc github](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures)

**EDIT:**

I tried with my own Database:

```
MATCH (p:User) return apoc.map.submap(p{.*}, ["username", "uuid"], null, true)
```

Output:

```
{
    "uuid": "1d69d...",
    "username": "admin......"
}
```

If you can't make it work, you could try something like this (not exactly the same output as requested):

```
MATCH (p:User) WITH apoc.map.values(p{.*}, ["username", "uuid"], true) AS values UNWIND values[0] as username UNWIND values[1] as uuid return username, uuid
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I already installed apoc plugin and it was working for other issues. For example apoc.map.values() works perfectly.

Comment: It's weird because the error you get indicates that this function has not been declared on your Neo4j installation, you should try to update or reinstall it maybe.

Comment: Sure I will try doing that. All I need is a key value pair in a sub map.

Comment: I updated my apoc plugin and it worked. Thank you so much for shedding some light!